# Repository related methods return only null values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Spring Boot application in which I have created an entity, a repository and a service.

I save entities in the database via transactions and everything works fine, my database is populated as I would expect. Also, I should mention that my database is created in PHPMyAdmin.

I also created a repository in order to fetch some data from the database by extending the Crud Repository. I also have a service which stores the methods that call the repository.

Though, none of the methods I have return anything ( my database is not empty ) and I do not know why. I have also tried adding @EnableJpaRepositories and @ComponentScan for the entity, but this did not work. Below are my classes:

The entity ( I will not put all the getters and setters here) :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "matches", schema = "tennis", catalog = "")
public class MatchesEntity {
    private int id;
    private String namePlayer1;
    private String namePlayer2;
    private int setsPlayer1;
    private int setsPlayer2;
    private String odd1;
    private String odd2;
    private String competition;
    private String surface;
    private String status;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Name_player1")
    public String getNamePlayer1() {
        return namePlayer1;
    }

    public void setNamePlayer1(String namePlayer1) {
        this.namePlayer1 = namePlayer1;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Name_player2")
    public String getNamePlayer2() {
        return namePlayer2;
    }

    // other getter & setters
}
```

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MatchesRepository extends CrudRepository<MatchesEntity, 
Integer> {

     List<MatchesEntity> getAllBySurface(String surface);

}
```

The service:

```
@Service
public class MatchesService {

@Autowired
MatchesRepository matchesRepository;

public int countMatchesOnHard() {
    return matchesRepository.getAllBySurface("hard").size();
}

public MatchesEntity findMatchById() {
    return matchesRepository.findById(2378).get();
}

}
```

The main class:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses={MatchesRepository.class})
 @EntityScan(basePackageClasses=MatchesEntity.class)
 public class PicksApplication {

     @Autowired
     static MatchesService matchesService;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         MatchesEntity matchesEntity = matchesService.findMatchById();
         int numberOfMatchesOnHard = matchesService.countMatchesOnHard();
         System.out.println(numberOfMatchesOnHard);
   }
}
```

Any method I try which is repository related returns null.
Can anyone help me with a suggestion ?

Comment: Can you share the code where a "match" is saved?  The getAllBySurface method is case sensitive are you sure the value is exactly what you have specified?

Comment: It works perfectly in my local, are you sure you have data in database? Why not create a simple `MatchesEntity` and save it before getting it in your `main` method? No need for `@EntityScan` or `@EnableJpaRepositories` btw

Comment: Oh, you are doing things on `main` method? Please revert that to `SpringApplication.run(PicksApplication.class, args);`, that is your problem not `jpa`, use `CommandLineRunner` feature and use `run` method not the `main` there. Like [this example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app), use `run` method with `implements CommandLineRunner`, not `main` method, that should only do `SpringApplication.run()`

Comment: Did you check my answer? It ought to fix the issue, apart from your main class, everything else works on my local

Answer (score 2):

Your main class `PicksApplication` is troublesome. The `main` method must trigger `SpringApplication.run` for the spring boot to initialize itself & the context for autowires to work. You are breaking all that within your code. You can utilize [`CommandLineRunner`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app) and add your code in `run()` method.

Like this;

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PicksApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MatchesService matchesService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PicksApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
         MatchesEntity matchesEntity = matchesService.findMatchById();
         int numberOfMatchesOnHard = matchesService.countMatchesOnHard();
         System.out.println(numberOfMatchesOnHard);
    }
}
```

then it ought to work, rest of the code looks OK